# Get ID information from button in ion-item in ion-list

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ionic-framework

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item-group *ngFor="let group of groupedContacts">
      <ion-item-divider color="light">{{group.letter}}</ion-item-divider>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let contact of group.contacts" class="contactlist"  style="clear: both;">
        <ion-col>
        <a start no-padding no-margin>{{contact.name}}</a>
        <p start no-padding no-margin>{{contact.number}}</p>
        </ion-col>
          <ion-label>
            <ion-button end float-right round>Tag</ion-button>
          </ion-label>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-item-group>
  </ion-list>
```

The code above is what I use to list my contacts.

My goal is to have the button in that **ion-item** within the **ion-label** to, when pressed, get the `contact.name` and `contact.number` of that item.

How can I do that?

**EDIT:** This will be a function called by the button in the .ts file

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let contact of group.contacts" ...>
...
    <ion-button (click)="processContact(contact)">Click</ion-button>

</ion-item-group>
```

and in .ts code add function

```
public processContact(contact) {
    console.log(contact.name, contact.number);
}
```